# Is 4:30 enough time to transfer from Orly to CDG?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-transfer, paris, short-connections

I want to book a flight from Bucharest to Buenos Aires and I've found a good price with Air France which has a layover in Paris.

The only problem is that I should arrive on Orly airport and continue the next segment from CDG airport.

There are 4h30m between the flights.

Is it a safe option? Also, should I take my luggage with me between the airports or would the air company do that?

Comment: Would that be on a single ticket? What date and time are you considering?

Comment: Anecdotical: I think this is safe enough but make sure that you plan ahead of time: know which RER (train) line to take, where to get the tickets, now your terminal in CDG and to do it efficiently.

Comment: I don’t think there are any Air France flights from Bucharest to Orly... Do you have another connection before that, or is that flight on a different airline?

Comment: @jcaron this is the skyscanner result. I talk about the first leg

Comment: Can you please include details of the routing? I can’t find any combination of flights from Bucharest to Buenos Aires which would include an ORY/CDG transfer...

Comment: @jcaron I just posted another question with this information: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122711/any-sure-information-about-air-france-free-allowed-baggage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If both flights are on the same ticket and Air France are willing to sell that connection, that means they think you can do it.

If you are arriving directly from Bucharest (or another non-Schengen airport) you would have to go through passport control first.

Then, in all cases, you would have to pick up your luggage, and get to CDG. There are multiple options for this, the easiest one using public transport is probably to take the bus “Le Bus Direct” line 3 operated by ADP directly from Orly to CDG. This would take about 1h15, possibly more if there’s heavy traffic, plus time to buy your ticket and wait for your bus. It also depends on which terminals you use.

You could also take Orlyval then RER B. It’s slightly longer, but is less dependent on traffic. Note that at peak hours the RER can be very very busy, so not the most comfortable ride.

The other options are of course a taxi or some private hire service like Uber, but it’s probably going to be more expensive, though it may be worth it if you are 3 or 4 (you might have a problem with space for luggage in that case though, make sure you get a large car or minivan).

You then have to drop your luggage (before the check-in deadline), go through passport control, security, and get to your gate.

I think the whole thing is doable, with a bit of margin to spare. If your incoming flight is late then it becomes more difficult, but (as long as it’s all on a single ticket), it’s Air France’s responsibility to take care of you if you don’t make it (provided you didn’t go shopping or sightseeing en route of course), rebooking you on the next available flight, and paying for meals and hotels if necessary.

If however the two flights are booked on separate tickets, then you are on your own. It’s definitely doable if everything goes as planned, but if your incoming flight is late or you have issues en route between the two airports, you’ll be considered a no show on the second flight, and your ticket will be cancelled (including the return flight). It will be up to you to rebook (and pay) for a new ticket.

#### Edit

Also forgot to mention that you will obviously need the right to enter French territory in this case, which may mean a visa depending on your nationality and status.

Comment: If Air France sells me that connection on a single ticket, why do I have to buy a bus ticket? Aren't they under an obligation to bring me from the start airport to the destination airport?

Comment: In [some situations you will get the bus ticket for free](https://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/guidevoyageur/aeroport/transfert_aeroports_paris.htm). But the general case is that you arrange and pay for your own transfer. There are many different options (bus, Orlyval+RER, taxi, Uber, etc.), it's your choice. The AF site is quite explicit about it during booking: "The Bucharest - Buenos Aires segment requires you to change airports in Paris. Transfer not included. You must collect your baggage before proceeding to your connecting flight." This is the general rule for inter-airport transfers.

Comment: @Alexander Air France is only obligated to provide that which is required by law and/or stipulated in your contract with them, i.e. their Conditions of Carriage and the rules specific to your fare.

Comment: "If both flights are on the same ticket and Air France are willing to sell that connection, that means they think you can do it." It means AF thinks people can get across Paris most of the time so AF will tolerate the risk of paying a crummy hotel. Whether anyone specifically evaluated OTP-ORY//CDG-EZE is a different question. One flight a day to EZE, EZE has lumpy demand (it gets sold out several days in a row), RER B is on strike more often than it isn't, the hotels and meals around CDG, even if on AF's tab, are not exactly comparable to San Telmo, ... not sure I would take this risk myself.

Answer (score 2):

The two airports are on opposite sides of the city and the minimum journey time seems to be around an hour, depending on the transfer type (bus, private taxi etc). https://www.paristoolkit.com/airport/paris_cdg_orly_bus.htm Personally I don’t think it’s a safe option.