# Any sure information about Air France free allowed baggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, flight-search-engines, backpacking, air-france

I want to book a multiple flight:

around January 3 2019: **Bucharest - Buenos Aires**

around April 16 2019: **Barranquila/Cartagena (northern Colombia) or Panama - Bucharest**

I will take with me a **70 l backpack** identically to [this one](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/forclaz-easyfit-70l-hiking-rucksack-dark-blue-id_8300845.html).

The problem that I have is that I'm not sure if I can take it for free as included baggage, I've found contradictory information and I would not want to pay a lot of money at the airport for my baggage.

So I took a look on skyscanner for flights. The cheapest ones I've found are done by KLM and Air France.

About **KLM** I took a reseach and I'm pretty sure that they don't allow more than 12 kg of luggage for free so my big bag would not fit in that. If not because of the weight for sure because of the dimensions.

Related to the **Air France** flight which can be seen on the search result [here](https://www.skyscanner.ro/transport/d/otp/2019-01-03/buea/ptya/2019-04-16/otp?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&ref=home#details/15116-1901031010--32677-2-11453-1901040940%7C15608-1904162000--32677-1-15116-1904181655), the things are not clear to me.

I select ebookers from the list under and it opens [this page](https://www.ebookers.ie/Flight-Information?langid=2057&piid=v5-34b23a5648103939a2dce5acac007b6b-0-8-1~0.S~AQoICL-mBBC-rwISCQioXBCWTxjdASABIAwgByANKAJYBA~AQpmCiAIwYwBEgQ2NjExGO58IM0gKOrYoAEwgNqgAThMQABYAQohCMGMARIENjIxNRjNICCuxAEo1dqgATCv26ABOExAAVgBCh8IwYwBEgMyMjgY4jAgpCYoy9-gATCY5qABOFJAAVgBCkQKIAjBjAESAzQ3NRjvxAEg4jAovOepATCo7KkBOFJAAFgBCiAIwYwBEgQxNTg4GOIwIO58KLn3qQEw4_ipAThMQAFYARIKCAEQARgBKgJBRhgBIgQIARABKAIoAygEMAE&clickref=1100l5F2VnMW&AFFCID=EBOOKERS-IE.META.PHG.SKYSCANNER.FLIGHT-CORESEARCH-DESK-EMEA-ECON&afflid=FLT.OTP.OTP.AF&action=UnifiedDetailsWidget@showDetailsForDeepLink&dcty=L1:OTP%7CL2:PTY&acty=L1:EZE%7CL2:OTP&ddte=L1:2019-01-03%7CL2:2019-04-16&cadt=1&adte=L1:2019-01-04%7CL2:2019-04-18&csen=0&cchl=0&ccls=3&rfft=N&sort=10&tytr=Multicity&price=693.64&ccyc=EUR&ptyp=air&serviceVersion=V5&messageGuid=082bf0d0-be62-11e8-a999-02f1472b9a8a&currency=EUR&paandi=true). I don't know if the link can be opened so I will put a screen shot.

**First flight:**

[image]

**Second flight:**

[image]

As you can see, the 1st checked in baggage and hand bag is for free. Great!

**BUT**

If I go to their [website](https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/local/resainfovol/aba/BagCalculatorAction.do?method=jspProcess) and search for my first segment for example, Buchares-Nice, it says that only a 12kg hand luggage is free and for a 23kg one I should pay 25/35$.

Can anyone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Some fares include a checked bag, other don’t (mostly on short haul flights). If your end-to-end fare includes a checked bag, that’s valid on all flights. Check the whole itinerary on the AF website to find out the allowance (probably 23 kg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baggage allowances aren't necessarily the same across an entire airline.  They can depend on your specific itinerary and also your booking class (e.g. Economy, Economy Flex, Business, etc).

In particular, it's pretty common that economy tickets include a checked bag when the itinerary includes a long-haul intercontinental flight, but not when it is entirely "domestic".  So it is entirely possible that you'd get a checked bag when flying from OTP to EZE via NCE, but not if you only flew from OTP to NCE.

And I think you're misinformed about KLM's policy: according to https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/baggage_allowance/index.htm, one checked bag is included on all intercontinental and European flights, except for "Light" fares.

Comment: Thanks for the info. About KLM, if you can see here: https://bit.ly/2xvh9ci, the return flight would be with KLM. Cartagena - Amsterdam - Bucharest. If you go on ebookers and see the details it says that for the 1st bag it must be paid 50-60 euros. It's a long-haul intercontinental flight and a pretty long european segment too

Comment: I would not necessarily trust the information from ebookers. Third-party sites are very often wrong about things like this. Try booking on KLM's website directly and see what it says.

Comment: Just had a look on their website https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/Baggage_Calculator/index.htm, for economy standard it is included, for economy light isn't. Can I find out which one is shown on skyscanner? :D

Comment: I don't use Skyscanner so I don't know where this information is shown, if at all.  You could ask a separate question about how to identify Economy Light fares, or more generally, the booking class, on Skyscanner.